# How do I make my Resume unavailable on Dice.com?

Tags: privacy

I posted my resume on Dice.com.  My job search is over, and I would like it to be unavailable to employers.  Obviously Dice is more interested in obtaining Resumes than deleting them, so they haven't made it obvious.

How do I un-post my resume, preferably without deleting the information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select Dashboard in the top navigation bar
2. Select Edit Profile on the top right of your profile
3. Click or slide the bar, just under the “Done” button on the top right, from Searchable “Yes” to Searchable “No”
4. Select a reason in the pop-up box and click Yes, Not Searchable
5. Click Done to complete the change

Comment: This is the current way to do it. The "Searchable" field is right there, but hard to see.

Comment: This is correct answer. It is SO hard to find i am tempted to unregister from Dice after over fifteen years.

Comment: Actually this information is no longer correct: there is no 'Dashboard' link.

Answer (score 5):

As it says in [this help page](http://www.dice.com/assets/help/help_seeker/WebHelp/myresume/my_resume.htm), make it *not searchable*.

Comment: This help page no longer exists

Answer (score 2):

1. Log into Dice
2. Go to Profile; 
   2b. Click on [Edit Profile]
3. On Right Hand side there is a button for Searchable
4. Turn to No
5. Your resume is no more Searchable on Dice

Answer (score 2):

As of February 2017, you need to:

1. Log into Dice
2. Go to **Profile**
3. Click on **Edit Profile**
4. Underneath your Name and Address fields you should see a slider labeled **Searchable**. Click on this and select **Yes, Not Searchable**.
5. Click **Done**

From there, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I keep getting calls and emails weeks to months after selecting "Not Searchable", so I uploaded a text file named "Not Currently in the Market.txt" in lieu of a resume.

Answer (score -1):

Delete User option is now available on Settings page as well.

Comment: To improve this answer and make it more useful, please attache some further steps / screenshots / etc.

Answer (score -2):

> To delete your profile you can **click the MyResume tab at the top of your MyDice Welcome page. From here select  your resume and click Delete to the right.**
>
> If you would like to remove your complete Dice account, please email us at techsupport@dice.com with your Dice Userid email.

From http://community.dice.com/t5/Customer-Support/Resume-on-Dice/m-p/152250/highlight/true, hope that helps :)

Comment: The OP doesn't want to delete the info on their resume.

Comment: Sorry - it did look like that, from this: 

'Obviously Dice is more interested in obtaining Resumes than deleting them, so they haven't made it obvious.'

Answer (score -3):

1. Log in to dice.com
2. Go to profile
3. On Right Hand side there is a button for Searchable

Comment: This seems to be the [same information posted by anil](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/84129/21583)